# Ajax Post in Asp.net Core in .Net 6 is not working in Action method

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I am making an ajax call in cshtml like below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dl-dir-list').click(function(e){
        console.log($(e.target).data('path'));
        console.log(JSON.stringify({path: $(e.target).data('path')}));
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetFiles")',
            data: JSON.stringify({path: $(e.target).data('path')}),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error while getting files");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Action Method:

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetFiles([FromBody]string path)
        {
            return Json(_fileService.GetFilesFromDirectory(path));
        }
```

Issue is always path parameter is null.
What could be the issue? This is in Asp.Net COre, .Net 6 version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.Be sure `$(e.target).data('path')` contains value.

2.Change your code to:

```
data: JSON.stringify($(e.target).data('path')),
```

---

The whole working demo:

View:

```
                                             //be sure add this `data-path` attribute
<input type="button" value="Create" class="dl-dir-list" data-path="aaa"/>

@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.dl-dir-list').click(function(e){
                console.log($(e.target).data('path'))   //result: "aaa"
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetFiles")',
                    data: JSON.stringify($(e.target).data('path')), //change here....
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Error while getting files");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetFiles([FromBody]string path)
{
    return Json(_fileService.GetFilesFromDirectory(path));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like below,

```
 data: JSON.stringify({"path": $(e.target).data('path')}),
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some changes required to send JSON data to ASP.NET Core 6 Controller Action. Here I have created a sample with all changes required and test JSON data send via AJAX

1. Your controller action should look like following

```
[HttpPost]
[Consumes("application/json")]
public IActionResult PostDataTest([FromBody] Employee[] employees)
{
    return Json(employees);
}
```

2. Ajax method will look something like

```
var jsonData = [{"id":0,"name":"Very Long Employee Name with Many Characters 0","doj":"2022-08-21T11:23:24.1220131+05:30"},{"id":1,"name":"Very Long Employee Name with Many Characters 1","doj":"2022-08-20T11:23:24.1236139+05:30"},{"id":2,"name":"Very Long Employee Name with Many Characters 2","doj":"2022-08-19T11:23:24.1236164+05:30"},{"id":3,"name":"Very Long Employee Name with Many Characters 3","doj":"2022-08-18T11:23:24.1236167+05:30"},{"id":4,"name":"Very Long Employee Name with Many Characters 4","doj":"2022-08-17T11:23:24.123617+05:30"}];

var strJson = JSON.stringify(jsonData);

$.ajax({
        url: "/home/PostDataTest",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: strJson,
        success: function (result) {
            $("#txtJsonReturned").val(result);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            $("#txtJsonReturned").val("Error while uploading data: \n\n" + err);
        }
    });
```

I have created a sample to handle this scenario and posted it on GitHub https://github.com/rajabb/MvcCore6JsonUploadSample . I hope that should solve the issue.

Comment: @PeterJ did the same :). Thanks a lot for your suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Hi do you remove this line from the Ajax method and try it.
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

.Net core not accept the "contentType" field in ajax method.